# oetl.sh error: input type not supported:: class java.lang.Integer [OETLOrientDBLoader]

Tags: json, etl, orientdb

I keep receiving this error everytime a file is ingested:

`SEVER {db=wos1} input type not supported::  class java.lang.Integer [OETLOrientDBLoader]`

This is a preview of the data file I'm working with (trying to ingest the CSV file into a Graph). I am only trying to get the id, wos_id:string, pubyear and issn:string, but it keeps giving me the above error.

```
id,wos_id,pubyear,issn
0,WOS:A1971I866700004,1971,0010-4817
1,WOS:A1971L278700007,1971,0022-0418
2,WOS:A1971I418100006,1971,0011-6963
```

I don't understand why it's returning such an error? Is it an error?

this is the json

```
{
    "source":
    {
        "file":
        {
            "path": "/Users/anantm/onedrive/docanant/work/KL/orientdb/wos_testing/wosid_publications.csv"
        }
    },
    "extractor":
    {
        "csv": {
            "columns": ["id:long", "wos_id:string", "pubyear:long", "issn:string"],
            "columnsOnFirstLine": true
        }
    },
    "transformers":
    [
        {
            "command":
                {
                    "command": "UPDATE Publication set wos_id='${input.wos_id}' UPSERT WHERE wos_id='${input.wos_id}'"
                }
        },
        {
            "field":
            {
                "fieldNames": ["id", "not_imp", "wos_id"],
                "operation": "remove"
            }
        }
    ],
    "loader":
    {
        "orientdb":
        {
            "dbAutoDropIfExists": true,
            "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/wos1",
            "dbType": "graph",
            "classes":
            [
                {"name": "Publication", "extends": "V"}
            ],
            "indexes":
            [
                {
                    "class":"Publication",
                    "fields":
                        [
                            "wos_id:string"
                        ],
                    "type":"UNIQUE"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your ETL json configuration? Does it stop on the first line or after a while?

Comment: @RobertoFranchini added it up there! It seems to keep running until the end but prints this out everytime. I updated the types to pubyear:long but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: hey @RobertoFranchini any ideas? would really appreciate it! :)